# JQuery setInterval with pause on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, setinterval, fade, clearinterval

I am trying to get multiple divs to fade in and fade out. Then on hover, pause the animation. Then on hover out, continue the animation. Right now I've gotten this far, the divs fade in and out correctly, and on hover it stops. But when I hover out, the animation doesn't start again. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function startTimer(){
        $('#quotes .textItem:gt(0)').hide();
        timer = setInterval(function(){$('#quotes > :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#quotes');}, 1000);
    });

    $('#quotes').hover(function (ev) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function (ev) {
        startTimer();
    });
});
```

Here is my [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dswizzles/cc1bewvk/2/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function(){
    timer = function(){$('#quotes > :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#quotes');};
    $('#quotes .textItem:gt(0)').hide();
    var interval = setInterval(timer , 2000);
$('#quotes').hover(function (ev) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function (ev) {
    interval = setInterval(timer , 2000);
});
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cc1bewvk/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting calling `startTimer()` following `$('#quotes .textItem:gt(0)').hide();` for calling `startTimer()` as argument to [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) call.

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {

    function startTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $('#quotes > :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#quotes');
        }, 1000);
    };
    $('#quotes .textItem:gt(0)').hide();
    startTimer();
    $('#quotes').hover(function (ev) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function (ev) {
        startTimer();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cc1bewvk/6/